# Is it necessary to implement dispose method if a game uses only 1 screen?

Tags: libgdx

Is it necessary to implement dispose method if a game uses only 1 screen(class that implements ScreenAdapter)? If there is no screen transitions the memory will be anyway erased once the user quits app, which is ok.

Comment: See also [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24228816/1366431), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/305930/98794)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively allocated memory (which all the `Disposable` classes use) is not automatically reclaimed until the entire application is exited, but Android applications persist after the game activity is closed, so the memory is leaked. So if you are targeting Android, you must dispose of all `Disposable` instances in your `dispose()` method.

Comment: There's also the GPU memory to be leaked too. I forgot Android applications aren't cleaned up immediately...